# div positioning problem

Tags: html, firefox, xhtml, css

In FireFox 3.5, the following div does not push the page content down.  Rather, it overlaps.  IE 8 does not.  What can I do as a quick fix?

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;">blah blah</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position: fixed means, that the div should stay absolute to the view point (to the browser window). You can use for real absolute positioning:

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should overlap, position:fixed does that. Switch it to static or remove position. In both cases top becomes meaningless.

**Position fixed:** You can set the elements location by setting top right bottom and left. This will contain distance from the browsers border.
**Position absolute:** The same but now top right bottom and left will need the distance from the first parent which has "position: relative".

Answer (score 0):

Should this be "Absolute" rather than "Fixed"